# CSS counters written out in words

Tags: css, css-counter

I use CSS to count sections in an HTML document:

```
body {counter-reset: sect;}
section:before {
    counter-increment: sect;
    content: 'Section ' counter(sect, upper-alpha);
}
```

The result is:

> Section A
>
> Section B

How can I style the counter to output numbers written in English?

> Section One
>
> Section Two

I have a solution via jQuery (using an array of strings) but I am looking to **only** use CSS. Is there a way to do this *without* using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. There's a [spec in the works that allows setting custom glyphs and repeaters](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#counter-style-glyphs) but it's currently still in *working draft* status and I'm not aware of any browsers supporting it yet. I just tried Chrome latest beta and it certainly doesn't, and [MDN doesn't even seem to be aware yet of its existence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=counter-style) despite the current version being over 2 years old already.